# How can i remove the white space around my header class?

Tags: html

```
<div class="header"
<h1> some stuff</h1>
</div>

.header {
background-color:red;
padding:40px;
}
```

I have a similar set up like this. How can i make the entire header color cover all the space. I have a small white space around my header and I want to make the read cover the white.

Answer (score 0):

HTML puts margin by default. You need to remove that margin.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color:red;
  padding:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<h1> some stuff</h1>
</div>
```